# Save result from system command to a variable using subprocess

Tags: python, command, subprocess

I would like to get the first interface that is up on a linux machine. I am using `subproces`  and I have the following piece of code :

```
def get_eth_iface():
    awk_sort = subprocess.Popen( ["-c", "ifconfig | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | grep eth | head -n 1" ], stdin= subprocess.PIPE, shell=True )
    awk_sort.wait()
    output = awk_sort.communicate()[0]
```

But with this result will be printed to the console and won't be saved to the variable. How can I redirect this to the variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect the `stdout` to `subprocess.PIPE`. Following works for me.

```
import subprocess
def get_eth_iface():
    awk_sort = subprocess.Popen( ["dir" ], stdin= subprocess.PIPE, stdout= subprocess.PIPE)
    awk_sort.wait()
    output = awk_sort.communicate()[0]
    print output.rstrip()
get_eth_iface()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks that works good BUT : I have to do that `output = awk_sort.communicate()[0]`to get the actual interface name + I get the interface name with new line sign. How can I get rid of that ?

Comment: Just use the `rstrip` method on strings.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html:

> Similarly, to get anything other than None in the result tuple, you
>   need to give `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.

Sounds like a good advice. Add `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and see what happens.